# What are append(); and prepend(); limitations?

Tags: jquery

```
$("a").contents().each(function(){
        this.nodeValue = $.trim($(this).text()).replace("[Hello]","");
        $(this).prepend("Pre").append("End");
});
```

I want a `[Hello]` to be cut from every `a`, but at the same time I want a `prepend()` and `append()` functions to work. In fact, a `replace()` function works perfectly, but the other two fails. I get no errors in console though.

Please keep in mind that `nodeType` of `$(this)` is `3` so it's a `text` type.

Why aren't `append()` and `prepend()` working?

Comment: What should be the output of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery.prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

> The .prepend() method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element

But textNodes do not have children, so you cannot *prepend* or *append*  elements into them.

But you can use [jQuery.before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) and  [jQuery.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to insert content before and after the textNode:

```
$("a").contents().each(function() {
  this.nodeValue = $.trim($(this).text()).replace("[Hello]", "");
  $(this).before("Pre").after("End");
});
```

But you need to take care because for an `<a>some text</a>` the `some text` could consist out of multiple text nodes, normally this should not be the case, but you should be award of that.